# How to use numeric values as generics paramters in Rust?

Tags: templates, generics, rust

I am learning Rust as a beginner.
I'm curious about how can we use numeric values as generics parameters that will be compiled at compile-time similar to template in C++

This is an equivalent C++ code.

```cpp
template<class T, int dim>
struct vec {
    std::array<T, dim> data;
    vec(): data() {}
    vec(const vec<T, dim>& obj): data(obj.data) {}
    ~vec() {}
};
int main() {
    vec<float, 3> v3;
}
```

That code above will be compiled the same as

```cpp
struct vec {
    std::array<float, 3> data;
    vec(): data() {}
    vec(const vec<float, 3>& obj): data(obj.data) {}
    ~vec() {}
};
int main() {
    vec v3;
}
```

Comment: Const generics are still unstable, as noticed below, but you can try macros. They are more powerful in Rust than in C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [const generics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44580#issuecomment-488819344), which have yet to land in stable Rust. You may find an example [here](https://github.com/maplant/aljabar) using unstable Rust.

Comment: Just for the record, const generics [have been stabilized in 1.51](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/03/25/Rust-1.51.0.html).

Comment: Here is a link to a Rust blog discussion const generics: https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/02/26/const-generics-mvp-beta.html

Answer (score -8):

You know what, we actually have generics in Rust!

I strongly suggest you read through ["The Rust Programming Language", TRPL](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/).

And your question can be answer in [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-01-syntax.html).

You don't really needs the contructor and destructor in Rust.  Rust will do it for you. TRPL provides a solid [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=98ff7a7adfe42b31fcc56915da81d6ee).

Also, for vector, generic data type is already supported so you don't have to implement it yourself. Check [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-01-vectors.html) out.

Comment: "we actually have generics in Rust!" Yes but const generics are unstable, and not mentioned in the TRPL link you provided. [Link only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) are also discouraged on SO. "You don't really need […] destructor in Rust" Well, yes you do! The default destructor might not be enough for some cases.